# Scraping reviews from Webpage with JavaScript, JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium, scrape

I was trying with various options e.g. Selenium, BeautifulSoup...etc to scrape the following site/pages:http://item.jd.com/526444.html#comment. I am trying to scrape the review/sections: there are more than 6000 of them, are dynamically loaded by JS, jQuery...etc. I already read existing articles for days, without success so far. Your help would be highly appreciated. The site is in Chinese. I attached a screen shot below, so you know where part to look. Thank you! I tried Selenium, but it hanged every time. do not know why.
[image]

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from pandas import DataFrame
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path=r'C:\phantomjs')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\chrome')
driver.get("item.jd.com/526444.html#comment")

try:
    element =    WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID,'loadedButton')))
finally:
    print(driver.find_element_by_id('content').text)
driver.close()


driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)


import requests
from lxml import html
response = requests.get('http://pycoders.com/archive/')
tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
print(tree.xpath('//divass="campaign"]/a/@href'))

import sys
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
from lxml import html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup



class Render(QWebPage):  
    def __init__(self, url):  
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
        QWebPage.__init__(self)  
        self.loadFinished.connect(self._loadFinished)  
        self.mainFrame().load(QUrl(url))  
        self.app.exec_() 

    def _loadFinished(self, result):  
        self.frame = self.mainFrame()  
        self.app.quit() 


url = 'http://item.jd.com/526444.html#comment'
r= Render(url)
result = r.frame.toHtml()
jd = BeautifulSoup(result)
jd.find('span', {'class':'desc'})
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please provide code samples and the errors so we can guide you in the right direction.

Comment: @JeffC yes, I just updated the code. I tried different things, sorry the code is very messy. I tried Selenium, then it hanged for no apparent reason. I tried PyQt also cannot capture the review that I wanted. Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: Please provide the necessary page markup.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry... I forgot to mention that I don't know python so this is written in Java. Hopefully you can translate.

---

There are some really bad timing issues on this site. If you load the #comment URL, it should open the comment tab but it doesn't always so I had to add a click and even then it didn't always open. I'm going to leave the timing stuff to you since this question is not about that.

This code grabs the TABLE tag that contains each of the comment "rows". It then loops through that specific table looking for the comment and the rating. Right now I'm dumping the comment and rating class to the console. The rating class is in the format "g-star5" where 5 is the number of stars. You will have to parse those out and store them however you need them stored.

```
driver.get("http://item.jd.com/526444.html#comment");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[href='#comment']")).click(); // extra click, shouldn't be needed
List<WebElement> items = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("table.com-item-main"));
for (WebElement item : items)
{
    System.out.println(item.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.p-comment > span.desc")).getText()); // the item (?) text
    System.out.println(item.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.grade-star")).getAttribute("class")); // the item (?) text
}
```

Comment: I am using Python 34. for some reason. for some reason, I do not get response on the following code:      driver.get("http://item.jd.com/526444.html#comment") do you have to wait for long time using Java?

Comment: Sorry... I forgot that you wrote your sample in python. This is Java. I updated my answer to state such for others that come along later.

Comment: That page is pretty large and complex... and I'm not in China so it loads pretty slowly for me. :) I found strange issues when loading the original URL where sometimes it would switch to the comment tab and other times it wouldn't.